# How to prevent laravel json response from adding backslashes

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm having trouble parsing the json response from my API via javascript because of the backslashes being added returned by laravel. I noticed that if it was a model being converted to json, laravel has no problem sending it back with no backslashes. However, I'm using guzzle to access an API, and I have to add that API's response to my own custom response with some other data.

I've logged my response data before being sent back via `response()->json()` and here's the content:

```
array (
  'data' =>
  array (
    'checkout' => '{"timestamp":1600480972698,"status":200,"message":"Request processed successfully","path":"/checkout","data":{"transaction_id":"xxxxx","status_description":"Transaction ready for payment","payment_url":"http://abcdefg.com/abcdefg'
    'transaction' => '{"data":{"transaction":{"billable_id":5,"amount_due":2,"transaction_fee":0.06000000000000005,"amount_paid":0,"reference_id":null,"reference_no":"PTX-0920UI22QJU2","payment_type_id":9,"transaction_status_id":1,"updated_at":"2020-09-19T02:03:09.0000$
  ),
  'status_code' => 200,
)
```

But what's actually returned by the `response()->json($responseData)` is:

```
{
   "data":{
      "checkout":"{\"timestamp\":1600480972698,\"status\":200,\"message\":\"Request processed successfully\",\"path\":\"\/checkout\",\"data\":{\"transaction_id\":\"200919020252BEZ5305\",\"status_description\":\"Transaction ready for payment\",\"payment_url\":\"http:\/\/abcdefg.com\/abcdefg\/1.2.1\/index.html#\/confirm?bizNo=20200919121212800110170567600273184&timestamp=1600480989712&sign=ChbtFZnRH5Mkqlou2BrZZ6TSvhrChmaTUPJnvWok14bVgr1lqMp46mOHoMm%2Fcy%2FhbfUzMoKJ0aG4%2BEjN%2BpFJaW5NchzV6WaZmur1YjFmPzaHVom74kGZcsWeJymgU%2BGmfnyrRaYP971%2BBl4Jqv6NX4gpGsIhzRSsiZIK5cxmk5DHIvn4MTA2834gS3%2FLTfWiQYHmmhhux3FL7eC72IgjW%2BC87pa2GC6XP0BCbgRpyMNUdD%2F5hEoHVKiWdNi8K9WyFZyxOyj%2B73gY%2F4XUJf6wyCLUxg8l6L4xnE0meBOguB8Q2qhS33NUvqXQowsJTn%2BGGEBeu9b4JgKf2cIaPlxE7A%3D%3D&merchantName=APNorderAmount=2.00\",\"status_code\":\"OK.01.00\"}}",
      "transaction":"{\"data\":{\"transaction\":{\"billable_id\":5,\"amount_due\":2,\"transaction_fee\":0.06000000000000005,\"amount_paid\":0,\"reference_id\":null,\"reference_no\":\"PTX-0920UI22QJU2\",\"payment_type_id\":9,\"transaction_status_id\":1,\"updated_at\":\"2020-09-19T02:03:09.000000Z\",\"created_at\":\"2020-09-19T02:03:09.000000Z\",\"id\":77}},\"message\":\"Transaction successfully created.\",\"status_code\":200}"
   },
   "status_code":200
}
```

Note: There might be some unwanted characters in the json above since I only copied these from the laravel.log via nano/terminal on my elastic beanstalk server due to constraints that I can only access the API from my server since the IP has to be whitelisted.

Is these any way to return the data on my second code snippet without the backslashes?
I returned it with the exact code `return response()->json($response)->setStatusCode($response['status_code']);`

Comment: Is it alright to convert values of `checkout` and `transaction` to array before sending the response? I think that would solve your issue.

Comment: those are actually processed on my controller with json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES). I might have trouble having to convert them to an array since they come from an API and might have different results.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
return response()->json($response,$response['status_code'],[],JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

the json() method (from interface ResponseFactory) take the forth parameter as json option,

`JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES` indicate that the encoding op will not escape slashes

Answer (score 0):

in your model try to add this attribute. this is just example code.

```
public function setCheckoutAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['checkout'] = json_encode($value);
    }
  
    public function getCheckoutAttribute($value)
    {
        return $this->attributes['checkout'] = json_decode($value);
    }

public function setTransactionAttribute($value)
        {
            $this->attributes['transaction'] = json_encode($value);
        }
     
        public function getTransactionAttribute($value)
        {
            return $this->attributes['transaction'] = json_decode($value);
        }
```